# BLE different peripheral name on different devices

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am trying to connect BLE device using his hex number written on his peripheral name. but the peripheral name  is different for some reason on different devices.

[image]

What could be the reason for that?
also i tried to find it inside advertisementData but without success.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your device might have the shortened name in the advertisement data but have the longer one in the scan response.

If you're scanning while the app is in the foreground, you'll get the full scan response data, so it might not matter in your app. You just might have to ignore the first callback that doesn't have scan response data.

Comment: I am scanning while the app is in the foreground, what do you mean by first callback? `didDiscover peripheral` ? can you please explain little more ?